# Why I can not download the json fie from server by swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to download the json file from the server and parse it
When the sucess callback is run in download function , I use `fileExistsAtPath` function to find whether the file in location ,the result is not in

I use [swiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) to achieve download function

this is my code

```
func download(url: String, parameters: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?,success:((String) -> Void)!, failed:(() -> Void)!, errord:((NSError) -> Void)!) {
   var request = HTTPTask();
   let downloadTask = request.download(url, parameters: parameters, progress: {(complete: Double) in
            }, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
       if response.responseObject != nil {
          //we MUST copy the file from its temp location to a permanent location.
          let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
          let str = "\(paths[0])/\(response.suggestedFilename!)"
          let newPath = NSURL(string:  str)!
          let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
          fileManager.removeItemAtURL(newPath, error: nil)
          fileManager.moveItemAtURL(response.responseObject! as NSURL, toURL: newPath, error: nil)
          var isDir:ObjCBool = false
          let exits = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path, isDirectory: &isDir)
          if isDir {
              println("file is in")
          }else{
              // I can not found the file in path
              println("file is not in")
          }
          success(str)
      }
    } ,failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
          errord(error)
    })
}

@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {
    download("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", parameters: nil, success: { (path:String) -> Void in
        println("\(path)")
        var data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
        var error:NSError?;
        var playData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &error) as? NSArray
        var arrayCount = playData!.count
        println("\(arrayCount)")
    }, failed: { () -> Void in

    }) { (error:NSError) -> Void in

    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably be putting some error checking in your code. Does the response object you're getting back actually have a `response.suggestedFilename`? I notice you've copied and pasted that from the swiftHTTP examples, but I'm guessing your response might be different...

Comment: I find the download function is not sucessful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it
this is my code

```
public func download(url: String, parameters: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?,success:((NSURL) -> Void)!, failed:(() -> Void)!, errord:((NSError) -> Void)!) {
     var request = HTTPTask();
     let downloadTask = request.download(url, parameters: parameters, progress: {(complete: Double) in
             println("progress:\(complete)")
          }, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
             if response.responseObject != nil {
                 var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                 let paths = fileManager.URLsForDirectory( NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
                 let pathsURL = paths[0] as NSURL
                 let newPath = pathsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(response.suggestedFilename!)
                 if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(newPath.path!) {
                     fileManager.removeItemAtPath(newPath.path!, error: nil)
                 }
                 var error:NSError?
                 var sucess = fileManager.copyItemAtURL(response.responseObject! as NSURL, toURL: newPath, error: &error)
                 if error != nil {
                     println("copy error : \(error)")
                 }
                 if sucess {
                     success(newPath)
                 }else{
                     failed()
                 }
             }
         } ,failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
                errord(error)
     })   
}

request.download("http://demo.yousi.com/Public/file/data.json", parameters: nil, success: { (url:NSURL) -> Void in
        var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        var error:NSError?;
        var playData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &error) as? NSArray
        println("playDataCount:\(playData?.count)")

    }, failed: { () -> Void in

    }) { (error:NSError) -> Void in
}
```